Keep JSON formatting when sending content as a string in Power Automate Flow
My main goal is to update a JSON-file in a Azure DevOps repository using a Power Automate Flow.
Reading the JSON-file, editing the content, and writing it back works except for the JSON-formatting being lost during the Flow.
My limitation here is that the Azure DevOps API expects the JSON-file contents as a string. And when transforming my object in the Flow to string, the JSON-formatting is lost.
Doing this process natively in the Azure DevOps webpage I can see that DevOps itself is adding "\r\n" with "" and "" to keep the formatting.

A solution could be to do the same in the Flow, but I can't seem to find a good way to create the same formatting.
I have tried several ways with replace to get the same formatting, but the formatting doesn't end up as the same.
replace(replace(replace(replace(string(variables('jsonobject')), ',"', ',\n  "'), '{', '{\n  '), '}', '\n}'), '},', '},\n')

(In the actual Compose \n is actually a newline in the editor, not the string "\n" fyi)

Is there a way of accomplishing this?

Yep, I have a solution but you have to be willing to use a third party connector.

Which connector is that? Third party might work

It's the Advanced Data Operations connector.  Will provide you with an answer to see if you're happy with it.

You can use the C# Script Execute operation within the Advanced Data Operations connector in order to format your JSON with indentation, etc.
It's very affordable but it's not for everyone.  I swear by this connector.
https://statesolutions.com.au/c-script-execute/
https://statesolutions.com.au/pricing/

Initialize Data
That's a JSON object as a true object, i.e. not a string.  This is the data I tested with shown in a minified form ...
{"Property1":"Value 1","Property2":"Value 2","Property3":[1,2,3,4,5],"Property4":{"Property4.1":"Value 4.1","Property4.2":"Value 4.2","Property4.3":"Value 4.3"}}

... the assumption here is that this is the data you're working with after you've edited it.
C# Script Execute
This is where the magic happens and it's real simple.

The parameters are ...
Script =
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters.dataToFormat, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

Parameters =
{
  "dataToFormat": @{variables('Data')}
}

Compose Result
This is to simply pull out the results and store it in a Compose statement.
body('C#_Script_Execute')['returnValue']

This is the result, a formatted and nicely indented structure ...
"{\r\n  \"Property1\": \"Value 1\",\r\n  \"Property2\": \"Value 2\",\r\n  \"Property3\": [\r\n    1,\r\n    2,\r\n    3,\r\n    4,\r\n    5\r\n  ],\r\n  \"Property4\": {\r\n    \"Property4.1\": \"Value 4.1\",\r\n    \"Property4.2\": \"Value 4.2\",\r\n    \"Property4.3\": \"Value 4.3\"\r\n  }\r\n}"

